# UITextField Tabbing Issues

Tags: ios

I have several UITextField controls on the view. One of them is a calendar. When the user clicks on the textfield it shows a calendar. The problem comes when the user press tab when inside a different textfield. The tab button iterates through all the textfields controls and then make the calendar appear.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    BOOL shouldShowKeyboard = YES;

    if(textField.tag == PLANTED_DATE_TEXTFIELD) // PLANTED_DATE_TEXTFIELD is 1 
    {
        [self.view addSubview:calendar];
        shouldShowKeyboard = NO;

    }

    return shouldShowKeyboard;
}
```

The textFieldShouldBeginEditing is fired 4 times one for each UITextfield controls when the user presses the tab. This produces the calendar to show up which I do not want.

Comment: couldn't understand your problem exactly..

Comment: I don't want to show the calendar when the user presses the tab key.

Comment: where is the tab key actually??

Comment: I think you are doing correct in your above code.. I don't what problem you are getting..

Comment: Normal tab key which is part of the keyboard! Tab, Return, Shift (The keys of the keyboard)

Comment: Tab only exists on the physical keyboard but not on the virtual onces that come with iOS. Since Tag does not exist it might be using order of the subviews to decide which TextField comes next (or it might just be random). Anyway, iOS devices have no tab. Physical keyboards are not part of any public API. So, I would not implement it, nor try to solve any bugs that come with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}



-(IBAction) textFieldEditingChange:(id) sender
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) sender;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [self.view addSubview:calendar];

}
```

The textFieldEditingChange is hooked up to the UITextField editingDidBegin event.